# Unity: Change scene by drag

Tags: unity, android, game-mechanics

How do I change the scene like you do on common android home screens?

I know i could detect if the player swipes to the right and then change the scene but this would not look as smooth as android home screens.

Comment: _"this would not look as smooth as android home screens"_ Why not? Did you even try?

Comment: Of course I've tried it. The Player swipes to the right and the new scene just instantly pops up.

Comment: have a photo of the new scene and move towards it and when you were sure it is in place load the new scene.hopefully it will be replaced and not noticeable

Comment: What if the new screen dynamically changes during runtime. Is there a way to take a picture of a scene by coding?